# Launching Camera App Using Javascript in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, hybrid-mobile-app

Is it possible to launch the camera app via Android JSInterface?Currently I can access the test() via javascript from the android code.I want to launch the camera app via javascript by using JSInterface.

**jQuery:**

> ```
>   $(function() {
>       FastClick.attach(document.body);
>       $('.btn-primary-panel').click(function(){
>         alert(android.test());// WebViewFragment.Java->JsInterface->getPhoneNumber
>       });
>   });
> ```

**Android Code:**

```
  public class JsInterface{
      public String test()
      {
          // Here call any of the public activity methods....
          return "WebViewFragment.Java->JsInterface->getPhoneNumber";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
public class JsInterface{
      public void launchCamera()
      {
          Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
      }
}
```

And don't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

And then just use

`android.launchCamera()` from JS.